# Are the components in series/parallel to the output voltage & current?

Tags: current, dc-dc-converter, parallel, series

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f2U1Dt.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Is the load(R1) considered to be in series or parallel to the output voltage from the boost-converter? From point A-B for any component placed there, is it in series to the output voltage & current?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRpFQ3.png)</sup>

Likewise for a buck-converter.

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. A component cannot be said to be in parallel or in series with a current or voltage. There's a voltage 'across' the load and a current 'through' the load.

Comment: We typically only use the terms series/parallel to describe the arrangement of *components*, not the locations of voltages/currents.

Comment: http://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/direct-current/chpt-5/what-are-series-and-parallel-circuits/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have made this into kind of a complicated question because you want to consider the "voltage output" as a single component. So Let's consider the voltage output to just be a two-terminal device. When two terminal devices are connected together so that they have the same voltage they are in parallel. When they have the same current they are in series. When I say same voltage, I do not mean equal voltage, I mean that they share the exact same voltage nodes.

In this case, if the supply is taken to be a single device, then the supply and load have both the same voltage and the same current, so they are both in series and in parallel.

But if you want to consider specific components within the supply circuit, then you might get a different answer. The output capacitor is in parallel with the load. The diode in the boost is in series with the  parallel impedance of the capacitor and the load. The inductor in the buck is in series with the parallel impedance of the capacitor and the load.

This question strikes me as you trying to settle an argument with someone. If so, my suggestion is to not worry about winning arguments. Just try to advance your understanding of electronics. If I am mistaken, my apologies.

Answer (score 1):

> Is the load(R1) considered to be in series or parallel to the output
>   voltage from the boost-converter?

There are 2 sides to this that spring to mind: -

1. A boost converter doesn't produce an output voltage; it dumps energy into the output capacitor (and load) at (say) 100,000 times per second. The form this energy takes is current so you could say the load (which includes the output capacitor) are together in series with the output current.
2. When the transistor is open and held open and the capacitor voltage allowed to fall or rise to equilibrium, it will "assume" a value of Vin (minus one diode drop). This is kind of the bottom line for a booster - it's the do-nothing scenario where the output approximately equals the input. You can argue that the load (and capacitor) are in parallel with a voltage source.

Make your own mind up how you wish to think about it because it's trivial really.

Comment: Andy this is related to that previous question, about V2 being placed on the output. What if, there is a voltage placed at point A before the load, what is the voltage there? Vo - V2 = Vr ?